# displaying error message only the input field has class error

Tags: css

My code snippet looks like

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xm-5 nopadding">
  <div class="col-xs-12 small-wrapper">
    <h5>Username</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 small-wrapper">
    <input class="error" type="text" name="username"  data-field="username"  />
  </div>
</div>
<p class="mismatched">Username error message</p>
```

And unfortunately I can't change the layout of complete form. Now I am trying to show ".mismatched"element if the username has a class "error"

I have no idea if there exists any css selector which can select an element in such struct or is there some other way or is it possible to do with css?

Comment: If your class `col-xs-12 col-xm-5 nopadding` can have the *error*, then it can possible to make `mismatched` element to `display: block` using `+` selector. As: `.error + .mismatched { display: block}`

Comment: Do you have control over the javascript?

Comment: Use a data attribute instead and set it to true or false  -- https://jsfiddle.net/y4fz4jzz/

Comment: If you can make a small change to shifting the <p> tag after the <input> tag you can show hide the error. Basicall how this would work is the moment the input has a class "error" the .mismatched element would show, if the <input> does not have the class "error" the .mistmatched element wouldn't show. check the fiddle here 
https://jsfiddle.net/rp9o5r71/